# Problem getting stocks prices from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm doing some web scraping from yahoo finance (NVIDIA Stocks) and I'm wondering why when i run my code i get always the same value, but in my browser when i refresh the page i get differents values (as it should be), how can i fix it?

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import time

def Is_Number(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except:
        if(string == '.'):
            return True
        else:
            return False



session = requests.Session()
for i in range(10):

    Response = session.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA?p=NVDA")

    KeyWord = 'data-pricehint'
    Index = Response.text.find(KeyWord) + 26

    GoOn = True
    CurrentPrice = ""
    while(GoOn == True):

    if ( Is_Number(Response.text[Index])):
        CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice + Response.text[Index]
        Index = Index + 1
    else:
        GoOn = False

    CurrentTime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    print("# Price:",CurrentPrice,"at",CurrentTime)

    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try yfinance instead?:

> pip install yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
import time


def get_price() -> float:
    return yf.Ticker("NVDA").info.get("regularMarketPrice")


def run():
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"{i}: {get_price()}")
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Really useful thank you I think I'll use this library, but i'm still curious why my code doesn't work

Comment: your code does weird thing and I dont understand reason why you concat output: CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice + Response.text[Index]. Maybe you do not call the code as expected so you reuse session instead of creating new one?

Comment: I tried without 'requests.Session()' but it doesn't change, any other suggestions?

Comment: this is the output I get when I run your code while current price is 289.44: # Price: 277.19 at 20:54:43
# Price: 277.19 at 20:54:54
# Price: 277.19 at 20:55:04
# Price: 277.19 at 20:55:14
# Price: 277.19 at 20:55:24

Comment: Is it the output you would expect? If yes, then it tells me you look at wrong indexes in the html represented as string because when I inspect the url I can see 277.19 value there.

Comment: yeah but when the stock value changes also the value (in html) changes but my output remain the same, i resolve this issue by adding at the request User-Agent = myuseragent. I don't know why it works but it does XD